Undefined name 'GoogleMlKit' although the google_mlkit_face_detection package is installed in Flutter
I am currently working on a feature where I can take a picture using camera and then scan if there is any face found in the picture. I followed some tutorials online, however I am encountering an issue with the Google ML Kit functions. It seems that calling GoogleMlKit.vision.faceDetector(); leads to theerror: Undefined name 'GoogleMlKit'. (undefined_identifier at [rtwo] lib\face_detection_screen.dart:18)
This is my complete code:
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_face_detection/google_mlkit_face_detection.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:google_mlkit_commons/google_mlkit_commons.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class FaceDetectionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FaceDetectionScreenState createState() => _FaceDetectionScreenState();
}

class _FaceDetectionScreenState extends State<FaceDetectionScreen> {
  final FaceDetector faceDetector = GoogleMlKit.vision.faceDetector();
  late CameraController _cameraController;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  bool _isDetecting = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeCamera();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeCamera() async {
    final cameras = await availableCameras();
    final camera = cameras.first;
    _cameraController = CameraController(camera, ResolutionPreset.medium);
    await _cameraController.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<XFile?> _pickImage() async {
    try {
      final XFile? photo = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      return photo;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error picking image: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _detectFaces(XFile? imageFile) async {
    if (_isDetecting || imageFile == null) return;

    setState(() {
      _isDetecting = true;
    });

    try {
      final inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(imageFile.path);
      final List<Face> faces = await faceDetector().processImage(inputImage);

      // Handle the detected faces
      for (Face face in faces) {
        final Rect boundingBox = face.boundingBox;
        print('Face detected: $boundingBox');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error detecting faces: $e');
    } finally {
      setState(() {
        _isDetecting = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Face Detection'),
      ),
      body: _cameraPreview(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final imageFile = await _pickImage();
          _detectFaces(imageFile);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _cameraPreview() {
    if (_cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      return CameraPreview(_cameraController);
    } else {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
  }
}


I have already installed the Google ML Kit(Face detection) in Flutter and also imported the package into the code but I have no idea why am I still having this issue.
This is my dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_fonts: ^6.2.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  firebase_messaging: ^14.9.1
  firebase_core: ^2.30.1
  camera: ^0.10.6
  path_provider: ^2.1.3
  path: ^1.9.0
  image_picker: ^1.1.1
  google_mlkit_face_detection: ^0.11.0


Remove import 'package:google_mlkit_commons/google_mlkit_commons.dart; and change   final FaceDetector faceDetector = GoogleMlKit.vision.faceDetector(); to   final FaceDetector faceDetector = FaceDetector( options: FaceDetectorOptions(),);
google_mlkit_commons is a different package.
